# Copying React State object; modifying copied object changes state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to copy a state object:

```
@boundMethod
private _onClickDeleteAttachment(attachmentName: string): void {
    console.log("_onClickDeleteAttachment | this.state.requestApproval[strings.Attachments]: ", this.state.requestApproval[strings.Attachments]);

    let requestApprovalClone = {... this.state.requestApproval}

    if (requestApprovalClone === this.state.requestApproval) {
        console.log("they are ===");
    }
    else {
        console.log(" they are not ===");
    }

    _.remove(requestApprovalClone[strings.Attachments], (attachment: any) => {
        return attachment.FileName === attachmentName;
    })

    console.log("_onClickDeleteAttachment | this.state.requestApproval[strings.Attachments]: ", this.state.requestApproval[strings.Attachments]);
    console.log("_onClickDeleteAttachment | requestApprovalClone[strings.Attachments]: ", requestApprovalClone[strings.Attachments]);
}
```

[image]

The `state` object is being altered too.  From what I have read, I shouldn't mutate a `state` object but only change it with `setState`.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting that behavior, because the

`let requestApprovalClone = {... this.state.requestApproval}`

is only shallow copying the data, your `attachments` property has some nested objects and it keeps the same reference and therefore when changing it, the cloned object gets altered and the state too.

To avoid that, you can perform another copy of your `attachments` property like this :

```
let attachments = [...requestApprovalClone[strings.Attachments]];
_.remove(attachments, function (attachment)  {
  return attachment.FileName === attachmentName;
});
```

Changing the attachments variable content won't afftect the state anymore.

you can read more about that behavior [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/copying-stuff-in-javascript-how-to-differentiate-between-deep-and-shallow-copies-b6d8c1ef09cd)

Answer (score 5):

It has to to with the way that JS handles their `const` references.

For those who feel adventerous:

```
let requestApprovalClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.requestApproval));

// modify requestApprovalClone ...

this.setState({
  requestApproval:requestApprovalClone
})
```

It would be interesting if `Object.assign({},this.state.requestApproval);` is faster than the whole JSON stringify/parse stuff or vice versa

Comment: gute Antwort Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like:

```
let requestApprovalClone = Object.assign({},this.state.requestApproval);

requestApprovalClone.strings.Attachments = requestApprovalClone.strings.Attachments.slice(); // will create a shallow copy of this array as well

_.remove(requestApprovalClone[strings.Attachments], (attachment: any) => {
        return attachment.FileName === attachmentName;
    })

this.setState({
  requestApproval:requestApprovalClone
})// If you want to update that in state back
```